# Having Python Error ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am experimenting with import sockets in python and I have a `client.py` and a `server.py` and when `server.py` receives a message from `client.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\PC\Programming\Codes\Redess\client.py", line 30, in <module>
    line = sock.recv(1024)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

My full client code:

```py
import socket

# Initialize Socket Instance
sock = socket.socket()
print ("Socket created successfully.")

# Defining port and host
port = 8800
host = '192.168.86.32'


sock.connect((host, port))
print('Connection Established.')

sock.send('A message from the client'.encode())

# request the list of files from the server
sock.sendall('list'.encode())
file_list_str = sock.recv(1024).decode()
file_list = file_list_str.split(',')
print('List of files in the server directory:')
for file_name in file_list:
    print('- ' + file_name)

# select a file to download
file_name = input('Enter the name of the file to download: ')

# request the file from the server
file = open("client_test.txt", 'wb')
line = sock.recv(1024)

# save the file data to disk
while(line):
    file.write(line)
    line = sock.recv(1024)

print('File has been received successfully.')

file.close()
sock.close()
print('Connection Closed.')
```

And here is my server file:

```py
import os
import socket

# Initialize Socket Instance
sock = socket.socket()
print("Socket created successfully.")

# Defining port and host
port = 8800
host = ''

# binding to the host and port
sock.bind((host, port))

# listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(10)
print('Server is listening for incoming connections...')

while True:
    # accept the client connection
    client_socket, client_address = sock.accept()
    print('Connection from', client_address)

    # send the list of files in the current directory to the client
    file_list = os.listdir('.')
    file_list_str = ','.join(file_list)
    client_socket.sendall(file_list_str.encode())

    # receive the client's file request and send the requested file
    file_request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(file_request.decode())


    if file_request in file_list:
        with open(file_request, 'rb') as f:
            file_data = f.read(1024)
    else:
        client_socket.sendall('File not found.'.encode())

    while (file_data):
        client_socket.send(file_data)
        file_data = file_request.read(1024)

    # close the socket connection
    client_socket.close()
    sock.close()
```

Don't know if the server isn't uploading the files that I have or something.
Have checked other stack overflow similar to this one but still can't fine a solution.